# problems with a mysql argument

Tags: php, mysql

i am have problems with my coding for sanitizing i keep getting this error come up

> Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in PATH on line 4

this is my code

```
<?php
function staff_exists($staff_username) {
$staff_username = sanitize($staff_username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'login' WHERE 'staff_username' = '$staff_username'"),0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a lot of functions nested there. Break them out into separate calls so you can isolate what is going on.

Comment: Just fyi, mysql_* functions are deprecated, consider checking out PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), the replacement. Also, indenting properly will help you maintain your code, and will help us decipher it as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below SQL syntax.

```
mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `login` WHERE `staff_username` = '$staff_username';");
```

Use backticks as `'` is used to string-delimiter.

Also, don't use `mysql_*` functions, [they are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: still wont work because '$staff_username' is between single-quotes, php can not interpret the value

Comment: Yes it can. The value is surrounded by `"` for PHP, not `'` which is just part of the value passed to `mysqli_query()` function.

Comment: i am now get the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: thank you very much i got it to work now you get the improve only problem is yours using mysqli and i am using mysql

Comment: Well, you can easily use the `mysql_query()` function instead but please, [**don't**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function staff_exists($staff_username) {
$staff_username = sanitize($staff_username);
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM 'login' WHERE 'staff_username' = '".$staff_username."'"),0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

changed '$staff_username' changed to '".$staff_username."'"

Comment: No need for concatenating variable when `"` quotes are used.

Comment: Column and table names should be backticked, not quoted.